# error: The media family on device is incorrectly formed

Tags: c#, sql-server

hello friends i am downloading database backup. But occurs error

```
The media family on device 'D:\sql backup\SQL2008R2_797817_headstart_backup_.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3241)
```

My c# code to download backup is given below:

```
Dim s As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm tt")
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
If iPointer = 0 Then
wc.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
Dim SqlServer As String
SqlServer = wc.DownloadString("ftp")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:/BluePearlsData" & "\SQL2008R2_797817_headstart_backup_" & s & ".bak", SqlServer, False)
```

Please help me ! Thanks in advance

Comment: You should at the very least be treating it as binary not text.

Comment: @MartinSmith  You mean to say should i use WriteAllBytes function in place of WriteAllText?

Comment: You probably want to remove your actual FTP site from the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlServer = wc.DownloadString("ftp://ftp.bluepearlreports.com/_database/SQL2008R2_797817_headstart_backup.bak")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:/BluePearlsData" & "\SQL2008R2_797817_headstart_backup_" & s & ".bak", SqlServer, False)
```

You need to change these to

```
`wc.DownloadData`
```

and

```
`WriteAllBytes`
```

respectively.

You'd be better off streaming it though, as this loads the entire DB backup into memory.

Comment: System.Net.WebClient not gives any function of downloadBytes